# how to use array_merge_recursive on 1 array with same keys

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

i have 1 array like below :

```
 0 => array:4 [
    "id" => "1"
    "date" => "2021-08-03"
    "from_time" => "09"
    "to_time" => "14"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [
    "id" => "2"
    "date" => "2021-08-03"
    "from_time" => "09"
    "to_time" => "14"
  ]
```

now what i want to do ?? as you can see the `date` and `from_time` and `to_time` have the same value . i want to merge them to 1 item like below :

```
 0 => array:4[
    "date" => "2021-08-03"
    "from_time" => "09"
    "to_time" => "14"
    "id" => ["1" , "2"]    
  ].
```

so i can have the same day ids in 1 index of array and if for example the same date and time got 4 ids i get the `id` key with 4ids . i used `array_merge_recursive` but it didnt help me with the same keys of an array
this is how i am building the array :

```
 
 foreach ($arrays as $key => $array) {

            $options[$key]['id'] = last(str_split($array['id']));
            $options[$key]['date'] = substr($array['id'],0,-2);
            $options[$key]['from_time'] = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($array['pickup']['from'])->format('H');
            $options[$key]['to_time'] = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($array['pickup']['to'])->format('H');
        }
```

. thanks in advance for help

Comment: are the y always the same value ?

Comment: yes they are always the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
//define items
$items = [
    [
        "id" => "1",
        "date" => "2021-08-03",
        "from_time" => "09",
        "to_time" => "14",
    ],[
        "id" => "2",
        "date" => "2021-08-03",
        "from_time" => "09",
        "to_time" => "14",
    ]
];

$options = [];

//loop through the items
foreach ($items as $item) {
    //set up the hashing key to use to locate if we hit dup entry
    $key = "{$item['date']}-{$item['from_time']}-{$item['to_time']}";

    //if indexing key not in options = never looked at it before
    if (!array_key_exists($key, $options)) {
        //have the key points to the current entry
        $options[$key] = $item; //attach the whole item to it
        //we want the id to be an array to initialize it to be one
        $options[$key]['id'] = []; 
    }

    //gets here then we know options[$key] exists

    //if the item id not in the id array of our dict
    if (!in_array($item['id'], $options[$key]['id'])) {
        //add to it
        $options[$key]['id'][] = $item['id'];
    }

}

//array_values to get the values and not worry about the keys
print_r(array_values($options));
```

Comment: thanks that really helped me though i didnt understand what happened and wished if u could explain a bit :) but i accepted that as the right answer and thanks for that :D

Comment: I added comments. hope it helps

Comment: if you don't care about maintaining the items array + less memory usage you can have a 

while ($item = array_pop($items)) {

 in place of 

foreach ($items as $item) {

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```php
$arr = [
    [
        "id" => "1",
        "date" => "2021-08-03",
        "from_time" => "09",
        "to_time" => "14"
    ],
    [
        "id" => "2",
        "date" => "2021-08-03",
        "from_time" => "09",
        "to_time" => "14"
    ],
    [
        "id" => "3",
        "date" => "2021-08-03",
        "from_time" => "14",
        "to_time" => "16"
    ]
];

$res = array_reduce($arr, function($carry, $entry) use(&$arr) {
    $matches = array_filter($arr, function($item) use($entry) {
        return $item['from_time'] === $entry['from_time'] && $item['to_time'] && $entry['to_time'];
    });
    //print_r([ $entry['id'], $matches ]);
    
    foreach($matches as $match) {
        unset($arr[array_search($match['id'], array_column($matches, 'id'))]);
    }
    
    if (!count($matches)) {
        return $carry;
    }
    $carry[] = [
        'id' => array_column($matches, 'id'),
        'date' => $entry['date'],
        'from_time' => $entry['from_time'],  
        'to_time' => $entry['to_time'],    
    ];
    return $carry;
}, []);
```